# Eclipse won't allow me to use an else statement while trying to validate user input

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class random {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("===== CS302 TOOL BOX =====");
    System.out.println("T > COIN TOSS SIMULATOR");
    System.out.println("G > GRADE ESTIMATOR");
    System.out.println("C > COLOR CHALLENGE");
    System.out.println("Q > QUIT");
    System.out.print("Type code letter for your choices: ");    

    String Menuchoices = "TGCQ";
    String initial_input = scanner.next();
    String code_choice = initial_input.toUpperCase();
    boolean code_letter;


    if (code_choice.equals(Menuchoices.substring(0,1))
              ||code_choice.equals(Menuchoices.substring(1,2))
              ||code_choice.equals(Menuchoices.substring(2,3))
              ||code_choice.equals(Menuchoices.substring(3,4)));
                 {System.out.println("success");}
    else {System.out.println("Failure");}

     }
}
```

Eclipse won't allow me to put this else statement in. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 10):

because of semicolon at the end of if statement, remove it

```
if (code_choice.equals(Menuchoices.substring(0,1))
          ||code_choice.equals(Menuchoices.substring(1,2))
          ||code_choice.equals(Menuchoices.substring(2,3))
          ||code_choice.equals(Menuchoices.substring(3,4)));
```